# Tinkerpop/Gremlin: select vertices together with outgoing edge count

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop

I try to find an efficient gremlin query that returns a traversal with the vertex and the number of outgoing edges. Or even better instead of the number of outgoing edges a boolean value if outgoing edges exist or not.

Background: I try to improve the performance of a program that writes some properties on the vertices and then iterates over the outgoing edges to remove some of it. In a lot of cases there are no outgoing edges and the iteration
`for (Iterator<Edge> iE = v.edges(Direction.OUT); iE.hasNext();) { ... }` consumes a significant part of the runtime. So instead of resolving the ids to vertices (with `gts.V(ids)` I want to collect the information about the existence of outgoing edges to skip the iteration, if possible.

My first try was:

`gts.V(ids).as("v").choose(__.outE(), __.constant(true), __.constant(false)).as("e").select("v", "e");`

Second idea was:

`gts.V(ids).project("v", "e").by().by(__.outE().count());`

Both seem to work, but is there a better solution that does not require the underlying graph implementation to fetch or count all edges?

(We currently use the sqlg implementation of tinkerpop/gremlin with Postgresql and both queries seem to fetch all outgoing edges from Postgresql. This may be a case where some optimization is missing. But my question is not sqlg specific.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to know whether edges exist or not then you should `limit()` results in the `by()` modulator:

```
gremlin> g.V().project('v','e').by().by(outE().limit(1).count())
==>[v:v[1],e:1]
==>[v:v[2],e:0]
==>[v:v[3],e:0]
==>[v:v[4],e:1]
==>[v:v[5],e:0]
==>[v:v[6],e:1]
```

In this way you don't count all of the edges, just the first which is enough to answer your question. You can do `true` and `false` if you like with a minor modification:

```
gremlin> g.V().project('v','e').by().by(coalesce(outE().limit(1).constant(true),constant(false)))
==>[v:v[1],e:true]
==>[v:v[2],e:false]
==>[v:v[3],e:false]
==>[v:v[4],e:true]
==>[v:v[5],e:false]
==>[v:v[6],e:true]
```